# Nested optimization with fmincon?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to do a multi-objective optimization with fmincon in which I minimize a secondary objective at each iteration of minimizing the primary. I was thinking of calling a second fmincon in the output function (set as an option) but how can I pass back the value of x (from this secondary) to the primary objective? Or what is a better way to go about implementing this approach?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you can always use an objective function that is itself a call to `fmincon`. If you can show an almost-working dummy example, we can clearly see what you mean, or what you don't understand. And anyway, expect anything with nested optimization to be very slow. If it's possible, you should try avoiding it.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to call `fmincon` inside your objective function.

Comment: Does this update the variable to the initial fmincon? If I call [x,f] = fmincon(obj(x),...) and then define function [u] = obj(u,...), my main confusion is if I can update x from obj. It seems it would just keep its value independent of what I do in obj. Thanks @dan, @ andras-deak

Comment: @user3557985 why would you want to manually update `x` from `obj`? That sounds like you're doing something wrong. You need to post a lot more details. What I was implying is that inside `obj` you might make another (independent) call to `fmincon` like `[y,g]=fmincon(obj2(y),...)` and then after that still inside `obj` determine the value of `u` based on `y`. If that's not what you want then you need to add way way more detail to your question.